# Original system and bakeoff meaning in NLP

Tags: python, nlp

So I am doing this homework in the one of standford courses and I managed to solve all the questions but I am trying to understand the last and correct me if I am wrong.

One it says build original system: That is building the model

The other one is bake off: That is comparing different models to each other to see the best one that perform the best.

Am I correct ?

This is the link to the homework: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqNj1dr8-HM

It is the very end. It is just that these terms very confusing and new to me

Thank in advance.

I need to know the exact steps for building the original system. What does it mean>? What is the bake off?

Comment: Yes you are correct with regards to "bakeoff", it is a term they use to refer to an intra-class competition between fellow students for a particular task.

Answer (score 2):

Backoff means you go back to a n-1 gram level to calculate the probabilities when you encounter a word with prob=0. So in our case you will use a 3-gram model to calculate the probability of "sunny" in the context "is a very".

The most used scheme is called "stupid backoff" and whenever you go back 1 level you multiply the odds by 0.4. So if sunny exists in the 3-gram model the probability would be 0.4 * P("sunny"|"is a very").

You can go back to the unigram model if needed multipliying by 0.4^n where n is the number of times you backed off.

Comment: awesome 
Thank you 
What about original system ? What does that mean?

Comment: I actually mean the meaning of bakeoff not back off